# RestAssuredRestDocumentationConfigurer causing NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, rest-assured, spring-restdocs

I am using Spring Boot and Rest Docs + Rest Assured to test my API. Here is my pom

```
<properties>
        <spring-restdocs.version>1.2.2.RELEASE</spring-restdocs.version>
</properties>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-restdocs-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-restdocs.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-restdocs-restassured</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-restdocs.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Here is my test

```
import com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured;
import com.jayway.restassured.builder.RequestSpecBuilder;
import com.jayway.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.restdocs.JUnitRestDocumentation;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import static org.hamcrest.core.Is.is;
import static org.springframework.restdocs.restassured.RestAssuredRestDocumentation.document;
import static org.springframework.restdocs.restassured.RestAssuredRestDocumentation.documentationConfiguration;

@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class OAuth2Test {

    @Rule
    public JUnitRestDocumentation restDocumentation = new JUnitRestDocumentation();

    private RequestSpecification spec;

    private Map<String, String> queryParams;

    private int serverPort = 8090;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        this.spec = new RequestSpecBuilder().addFilter(documentationConfiguration(this.restDocumentation)).build();
        spec.port(serverPort);
        spec.authentication().basic("myclient", "secret");
        spec.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        queryParams = new HashMap<>();
        queryParams.put("username", "joe");
        queryParams.put("password", "abcd123");
        queryParams.put("grant_type", "password");
        queryParams.put("scope", "read");
    }

    @Test
    public void testOAuth() {
        RestAssured.given(this.spec)
                .filter(document("token"))
                .queryParameters(queryParams)
                .when().post("/oauth/token")
                .then().assertThat().statusCode(is(200));
    }
}
```

But when I run it, I get a NullPointerException when RestDocs tries setting the configuration.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.HashMap.putMapEntries(HashMap.java:500)
    at java.util.HashMap.<init>(HashMap.java:489)
    at org.springframework.restdocs.restassured.RestDocumentationFilter.getConfiguration(RestDocumentationFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.restdocs.restassured.RestDocumentationFilter.filter(RestDocumentationFilter.java:59)
    at com.jayway.restassured.filter.Filter$filter.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at com.jayway.restassured.filter.Filter$filter.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.filter.FilterContextImpl.next(FilterContextImpl.groovy:71)
    at org.springframework.restdocs.restassured.RestAssuredRestDocumentationConfigurer.filter(RestAssuredRestDocumentationConfigurer.java:69)
    at com.jayway.restassured.filter.Filter$filter.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.filter.FilterContextImpl.next(FilterContextImpl.groovy:71)
    at com.jayway.restassured.filter.FilterContext$next.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1466)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1218)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1027)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:815)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:58)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.post(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:155)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.post(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
    at com.greeno.ralts.api.test.OAuth2Test.testOAuth(OAuth2Test.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.restdocs.JUnitRestDocumentation$1.evaluate(JUnitRestDocumentation.java:63)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Here is the `filter` method that passes the null Map that causes the null pointer

[image]

And the root cause of this is because the `properties` field of `context` (which is of type `FilterContextImpl`) is null

Maybe I'm messing up the setup or something? I am following the guide here
https://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/current/reference/html5/

Comment: Please don't format stack traces as blockquotes, it messes up all the line breaks, which are important for readability.  Please [edit] your post and re-copy/paste the properly formatted stack trace and then format as code.

Comment: @JimGarrison thanks for the tip, done

Comment: Not sure that it’s the cause of the NPE, but you need to use REST Assured 2.8 or later: https://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/1.2.3.RELEASE/reference/html5/#getting-started-requirements.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson You can post that as an answer if you'd like, that was indeed the cause of the NPE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring REST Docs 1.2.x [requires REST Assured 2.8 (or later)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/1.2.3.RELEASE/reference/html5/#getting-started-requirements) and you're using 2.7. REST Assured 2.7 doesn't initialise filters in the same way that 2.8 does. This is leaving `RestDocumentationFilter` in an uninitialised state which, in turn, causes the NPE.